# SQL Server Connection Reset/sec

Tags: sql-server, cpu

I am trying to determine if Connection pooling resets is causing my high cpu.  I have a server with 2000 batch/sec which doesn't seem terribly high yet I have 64 CPU at 40% or greater most of the time.   My wait stats all look glorious in my opinion.  No blocking but I do have quite a number of high memory grant pressure at times (perhaps 10% of my available workspace memory).   SQL 2019 and CU9.  Enterprise, 64 CPU, 1TB ram.

Comment: So, have you tried changing the connection pool parameters to see the affect on CPU?

Comment: Interesting point, no - but that's also not the question - the question is how do I measure the cost of the CPU and the resets.  This is production, I can't tinker with things.